# Button Like increment number, but dont post on facebook and the facebook do not recognize meta tags

Tags: facebook, button, increment

I'm trying to implement a 'like button' on my web site, and the preview function when you post the website link on facebook and it appear the title, description, image, etc.. etc..
I followed every step on facebook developers site, but it still doesn't work! Can someone help me please? Here's my code:

```html
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="pt-BR">    

    <meta property="og:title" content="Hostel Rosa dos Ventos"/>
    <meta property="og:type" content="hotel"/>
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.hostelrosadosventos.com.br"/>
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://www.hostelrosadosventos.com.br/Content/images/thumb_facebook.jpg"/>
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="RV Hostel"/>
    <meta property="fb:admins" content="100001714162833,1043531878"/>
    <meta property="og:description" content="Hostel localizado em Morro de São Paulo - BA"/>

    <title>Hostel Rosa dos Ventos</title>

    [...]
</head>

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
    // Load the SDK Asynchronously
    (function (d) {
        var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
        js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/pt_BR/all.js#xfbml=1";
        ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
    } (document));
</script>
```

and where i want the button:

```html
<fb:like href="http://www.hostelrosadosventos.com.br" width="450" height="80" show_faces="false"/>
```

whats wrong ?

When i try to debug it on

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.hostelrosadosventos.com

It says that my meta tags are not there...
i'm actually freaking out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be because these meta tags are not closed properly

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="pt-BR">
```

I know it shouldn't matter, but you don't know how sophisticated FBs parser is.  So please try

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="pt-BR"/>
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay, but I already had forgotten about this question! haha but it worked, thank you!

Comment: @Walter Ha!  Well at least you came back :)  A few times I've googled a problem I had, only to find the answer, and guess who wrote the question... me, years ago!

Comment: hahahaha I think many people already passed for it... It's too many things to remember